# Is there a way to add both stripslashes and mysql escape string to sanitize data?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just starting out and trying to learn php and mysql, so my level of knowledge is rather primitive to both.

I'm not too sure about the stripslashes method, so I wanted to know if the below code is secure enough to prevent an SQL injection or other malicious attack against my database? Would the database benefit from adding mysql_real_escape_string in addition to the stripslashes method?

```
$first = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['First']));
$last = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Last']));
$city = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['City']));
$state = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['State']));
$country = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Country']));
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email']));
$tempt = $_POST['tempt'];
$tempt2 = $_POST['tempt2'];


if ($tempt == 'http://' && empty($tempt2)) {

    $error_message = '';
    $reg_exp = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9­-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,5}$/";

    if(!preg_match($reg_exp, $email)) {

        $error_message .= "<p>A valid email address is required.</p>";
    }
    if (empty($first)) {
        $error_message .= "<p>Please provide your first name.</p>";
    }
    if (empty($last)) {
        $error_message .= "<p>Please provide your last name.</p>";
    }

    if (!empty($error_message)) {

        $return['error'] = true;
        $return['msg'] = "<p>The request was successful, but the form was not filled out correctly.</p>".$error_message;
        echo json_encode($return);
        exit();

    } else {

        $return['error'] = false;
        $return['msg'] = "<p style='top:9px; color:#ff6000; left:63px; text-align:left; font-size:1.50em;'>".$first .", <p style='top:0px; width:100%; left:63px; text-align:left; line-height:1.1em;'>your subscription request has been processed.</p>";
        echo json_encode($return);
    }

} else {

        $return['error'] = true;
        $return['msg'] = "<p>There was a problem while sending this form. Try it again.</p>";
        echo json_encode($return);
}
```

Comment: You should really use prepared statments to avoid any security issue either with pdo or mysqli. Mysql_* functions are deprecated

Comment: Not in addition, but instead, yes. Dbs have characters they don't like and only the db driver's functions know which. It's more than just escaping all `'`. And what Fabio said.

Comment: And if you're printing $first inside html, you should html encode it too. Escape it for the db, not for html. Html encode it for html, not for the db. Double is never good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a function. Just pass in the value to be sanitized.

```
function clean($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
    $new_enougth_php = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string");
    if ($new_enougth_php) {
        if ($magic_quotes_active) {
            $value = stripslashes($data);
        }
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    } else {
        if (!$magic_quotes_active) {
            $value = addcslashes($data);
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any DB queries in your code, but look to the comments for recommendations about prepared statements / no mysql_* functions, etc..

You only need `stripslashes` if `magic_quotes_gpc` is enabled in `php.ini`, try:

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
   $_POST = array_map('stripslashes', $_POST);
}
```